# Backbone View showing up with a reference error?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view

Hey I am not sure why this Backbone view shows as a reference error stating that UserView is not defined. The User model shows up as a function so that works. I ran my code with JSLint on jsfiddle too and there is no problems js wise, or is there?

Code below

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        firstName: 'J.R.',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        email: 'jsmith@knicks.com',
        phone: '212-424-6234',
        birthday: '03/05/1982',
        city: 'New York'

    },



    location: function(){
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName') + 'is currently in ' + this.get('city') + '.';
    }

});

var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.model.get('firstName'));
    }
});

var user = new User();
var userView = new UserView({model: user});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declear follow content in window.load function.

```
var user = new User();
var userview = new UserView({model: user});
```

Because if is out of window.load function, when you call the

object of UserView, it is not created at that time. :)

Comment: Those variables I added on the bottom do not matter. It is the fact that I have a function that is a view and it should note that it exists. The variables will never work if the UserView is not being picked up.

Comment: Thanks just had a friend come look at it, I didn't realize I was saving the file as a second main.js file so nothing was being changed in the other file. Thanks for all your help!